# How to use globs/wildcards when the -C option is used in tar command?

Tags: tar, wildcards, command, utilities

My directory structure is as follows :

```
/home/workspace/build/
```

---

```
/home/workspace/js/jai.1.js
/home/workspace/js/jai.2.js
/home/workspace/js/jai.3.js
/home/workspace/js/jai.4.js
```

I want to **tar** all **js** files whose prefix is **jai** that are in `/home/workspace/js/` directory to `/home/workspace/build/` directory.

Suppose name of the tar file that is created is **bundle.tar.gz**

So  **bundle.tar.gz** should contain following files

```
jai.1.js
jai.2.js
jai.3.js
jai.4.js
```

I want to achieve this using `tar` command instead of copying files to destination and then tar it.

**EDIT**

I want to tar it from `destination` directory i.e., `/home/workspace/build/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(cd ../js && pax -w jai.*.js) | gzip > bundle.tar.gz
```

Would do it (or replace `pax -w` with `tar cf -` if you have a `tar` command). The point is to change the current directory only for `pax`/`tar` by using a subshell.

Some `tar` implementations (`tar` is a very non-portable command which is why POSIX introduced `pax`) have a `-C` option that makes it change directory for the file collection but not for the file output. Those also generally support a `z` option to call `gzip` by themselves or implement the gzip compression internally.

However, things like:

```
tar czf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js jai.*.js
```

wouldn't work because that `jai.*.js` is expanded by the shell for which the current directory has not changed. With `zsh`, you could do:

```
tar czf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js ../js/jai.*.js(:t)
```

Where the `:t` modifier gets the *tail* (basename) of the files generated by the glob.

With `pax`, you can also do:

```
pax -'s|.*/||' -w -- ../js/jai.*.js | gzip > bundle.tar.gz
```

But note that the substitution to strip the leading path components would also apply to the target of symlinks (some `tar` implementations have similar options where you can specify whether you want those translated or not), and would also give a different outcome if any of those `jail.*.js` files were of type *directory* and contained more files.

With libarchive `bsdtar`, you can also do:

```
bsdtar zcf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js --include=. --include='jai.*.js' .
```

GNU `tar` has no `--include` by has a `--exclude`, so you could do:

```
tar zcf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js --exclude='*[^s.]' \
                               --exclude='*?.' \
                               --exclude='*[^j]s' \
                               --exclude='*[^.]js' .
```

(those would add an entry for `.` though)

With `star`:

```
star czf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js 'pat=jai.*.js' .
```

(would include `jai.foo/bar.js` though, and not non-matching files in `jail.*.js` directories)

```
star czf bundle.tar.gz -C ../js 'pat=jai.#[^/].js{%!/*}' .
```

(where `#<expr>` is like `<expr>*` in EREs and `{%!/*}` like `(/.*)?` (`%` is nothing and `!` is OR)) to do the same as `(cd ../js && tar czf - jai.*.js) > bundle.tar.gz`. It would also still crawl the entire directory structure for only selecting the files at the top level.

With newer versions, you can also use `-find`. So for the equivalent of our `(cd ...)` one that doesn't crawl into unnecessary directories but still include all the files in `jai.*.js` directories:

```
star czf bundle.tar.gz C=../js  -find . \
  \( \( -name '*.js' -o -path '*/*' -o -name . \) -o ! -prune \) ! -name .
```

Though more likely, you'd actually want:

```
star czf bundle.tar.gz C=../js \
  -find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'jai.*.js' -type f
```

That is archive only the `jai.*.js` *regular* files and only at the top level which with `zsh` you could also do with:

```
(cd ../js && pax -w -- jai.*.js(.)) | gzip > bundle.tar.gz
```

(`(.)` being a *glob qualifier* that restricts to *regular* files).

Comment: I'm blessed with your knowledge.

Comment: Are you same the **Stephane Chazelas** who found bug in internet security back in 2014?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, see [How was the Shellshock Bash vulnerability found?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/162287)

Answer (score 3):

No regex is required here.
You can use just plain shell asterisk like that:

`tar cvzf /home/workspace/build/bundle.tar.gz /home/workspace/js/jai.*.js`

If you don't want to retain directory structure, then easiest way is to `cd /home/workspace/js/` and then `tar cvzf /home/workspace/build/bundle.tar.gz jai.*.js`

Comment: Sir I already specified that I don't want directory structure in my tar file. I just  want files. Using this command it also stores the directory in tar file

Comment: Corrected answer accordingly, Sir :)

Comment: But I want to tar it from `/build` directory not from the source directory.